# Emulating Windows ACLs on ZoL impossible?

Tags: samba, zfs

I'm trying to set up a file server running ubuntu 16.04.2 with samba 4.3.11. I have set up a ZFS pool and now I'm trying to enable windows ACLs. However, I can't figure out how to do this with ubuntu. Apparently FreeBSD can do this though.

ZFS should be able to do ACLs, and I've been able to enable POSIX ACLs, but what I don't quite get is how to set things up after enabling POSIX ACLs, or if POSIX ACLs will do the trick, as they're quite a bit more limited compared to the windows model.

Is it possible at all to get this to work with ZoL? Is there a way ofr samba  to emulate windows ACLs with ZoL somehow?

It's not clear to me how to proceed further, so I'd appreciate some pointers on whether this is possible with linux, or if it's better to set this up in FreeBSD. I would like to avoid adding another OS to my constellation if possible, as that would add another OS to keep track ofin terms of learning how to work with and in terms of security updates etc.

Comment: IIRC ZFS isn’t concerned with Windows ACLs at all. It’s all up to Samba to translate.

Comment: @DanielB I've expanded the question a bit. You're right about samba and I already had some info about the fact that in the end samba does the translation, but the samba wiki also says it depends on the underlying file system to implement this feature. So I'm still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @DanielB: Conveniently, ZFS (NFSv4) ACLs are _very similar_ to Windows (NTFS) ACLs.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, but that's where things become unclear. How do I set those up on ubuntu / ZoL?

Comment: ZoL does not use the same ACLs FreeBSD/Solaris do. It only supports the `posixacl` mode, which is essentially an emulation based on a system-namespaced extended attribute. However, according to the corresponding Samba Wiki page, this is sufficient.

Comment: Relevant (currently open) ticket regarding this feature: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/4966